# find and copy command: what if the file is already present or copied few minutes back?

Tags: shell, find, cp

I have a job that triggers the script, the job always runs in the background

```
nohup copy_files.sh &
```

In the shell script, I am running following code indefinitely using `while(true)` loop

```
find . -mmin -12 -type f -exec cp "{}" /tmp \;
sleep 10m
```

I want to copy files created in the last 10 minutes, to be on the safer side I am using `-mmin 12m`

I have couple questions here:

1. If `/temp` already has a file with conflicting filename, will it get overridden on the file copy will be skipped?
2. Is there any other condition that I need to take care of?

Comment: 1. yes, such as `./a/file.txt` and `./b/file.txt` both get copied to `/tmp/file.txt`; 2. such as what? What is your goal here, are you trying to flatten a directory hierarchy? Are you trying to backup a directory hierarchy?

Comment: say `a.txt` is already present in the `/tmp/`, now if `find` tries to copy different file having name a.txt. what will happen? Skip copy or override new file?

Comment: You might be more efficient with `inotifywait` (there are several Q/A on this site that use this tool to copy recently-arrived files). Assuming Linux OS, that is.

Comment: @GovindaSakhare, overwrite.